# Getting [Function: (function name)] instead of expected output

Tags: javascript, function

I'm currently learning some Javascript through Codecademy and I ran into this problem. When I run my program I get [Function: getComputerChoice] output to the console instead of what I'm expecting.

Here's my code:

```
function getComputerChoice() {
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    switch (getComputerChoice) {
      case 0:
        return 'rock';
        break;
      case 1:
        return 'paper';
      case 2:
        return 'scissors'
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: `switch (getComputerChoice)` - What are you expecting here? `getComputerChoice` is the function name.

Comment: I was trying to use invoke the math.random method to generate a random number then check to see what number was generated and return the string associated with that number

Comment: In that case, you probably want: `switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3))`

Comment: Ah got it, still getting [Function: getComputerChoice] when I console.log        function getComputerChoice() {  
     switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)){
      case 0:
        return 'rock';
        break;
      case 1:
        return 'paper';
        break;
      case 2:
        return 'scissors'
        break;
    }
}

Thanks again for your patience and your help.

Comment: Got it now, it's because I was using console.log(getComputerChoice) without the extra set of parentheses to encapsulate the parameters. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `()` are used to _invoke_ the function. You were logging the function instead of its return value by invoking it.